# 530, "5.7.0", Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: error-handling, server, google-workspace, starttls

My friend ask for help he has a new job but he encounter this issue.

220 : smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b190sm10750343lfd.39 - gsmtp

HELO Sage

250 : smtp.gmail.com at your service

MAIL FROM:

530 : 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b190sm10750343lfd.39 - gsmtp

5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b190sm10750343lfd.39 - gsmtp : Erreur No 25

They are using GSuite and accounting software SAGE they need to send report from sage to the registered email address but he told me he keeps on receiving this errors. Please i hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Less secure apps", if that doesn't work, enable 2FA and create an application password in GSuite to use with Sage.